# how to conjugate verb in dependent clause inside subjunctive mood

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, conjugation

In the sentence

> I pretended that I understood, lest he think I am stupid or deaf.

the "he think" part is definitely present subjunctive, but I'm not sure how the "I am" part should be conjugated. I'm thinking it might also be present subjunctive:

> I pretended that I understood, lest he think I **be** stupid or deaf.

or past subjunctive:

> I pretended that I understood, lest he think I **were** stupid or deaf.

All three sound all right to me. Is there one correct conjugation to use in this case?

Comment: This is archaic syntax, not found in modern English speech. Since people have used all sorts of constructions and called them "subjunctive" over the centuries, that means you can write practically anything and get away with it, provided you don't mind people thinking your writing is vaguely nineteenth-century. P.S. All those "sequence of tense" rules about "subjunctive" don't really predict what native speakers say, as you've found. More zombie rules, for the most part.

Comment: The only word that zips us back in time here is 'lest' replace that with 'in case' and change 'think' to 'thought' and it's something you might hear everyday. 'I pretended that I understood in case he thought I was stupid or deaf'

Comment: I don't think "in case" is quite the right phrase to use, since it doesn't imply the same sort of causality that "lest" does.

Comment: The third example is the correct one.

Comment: I don't think that _lest_ implies to modern English speakers the causality you attribute to it.  If you had to use one of these constructs, I suggest your verb tenses agree entirely or within the clause at least. _I pretended that I understood, so that he would not think I was stupid or deaf_ seems more natural and imbued with causality to me.

Comment: I thought about that, but using "I was stupid or deaf" rather than "I am stupid or deaf" makes it possible that I used to be but no longer am stupid or deaf.

Anyway, there are a lot of good answers here. I was just wondering. I don't actually talk like this, I think.

Answer (score 3):

None of those sound right to me.  I would write:

> I pretended that I understood, lest he think me stupid or deaf.

[Reference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lest+he+think+me%2Clest+he+think+I+am%2Clest+he+think+I+be%2C+lest+he+think+I+were&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clest%20he%20think%20me%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you studied clauses with lest in literature you would find all three possibilities. Even "should" can be used.

Answer (score 1):

"I were" is the correct subjunctive form here. However, "lest + subjunctive" marks the sentence as an archaic construction. Even "lest he think me", which is probably better, is subjunctive and feels old-fashioned.

If that's not what you intend, various modern alternatives are possible. How about, "I pretended that I understood, so he would not think I was stupid or deaf."